# Как добавить C-шный скрипт вместо библиотеки в arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

у меня есть код для ардуино

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <gForceAdapterC.h>
#include <gForceAdapter.h>
#include <gForceDataTypes.h>


#define GFORCE_FIST_PIN 2
#define GFORCE_SPREAD_PIN 3
#define GFORCE_WAVEIN_PIN 4
#define GFORCE_WAVEOUT_PIN 5
#define GFORCE_PINCH_PIN 6
#define GFORCE_SHOOT_PIN 7
#define Timeout 1000

#define gforceSerial Serial

/* returns char count */
int SYS_GetChar(unsigned char *data)
{
  int ret = gforceSerial.read();

  if (ret == -1)
    return 0;

  *data = (unsigned char)ret;

  return 1;
}


/* returns System time */
unsigned long SYS_GetTick(void)
{
  return millis();
}


void setup()
{
  // set pin mode to output
  pinMode(GFORCE_FIST_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GFORCE_SPREAD_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GFORCE_WAVEIN_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GFORCE_WAVEOUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GFORCE_PINCH_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GFORCE_SHOOT_PIN, OUTPUT);

  // default set output low
  digitalWrite(GFORCE_FIST_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GFORCE_SPREAD_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEIN_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEOUT_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GFORCE_PINCH_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GFORCE_SHOOT_PIN, LOW);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  gforceSerial.begin(115200);
}



void loop()
{
  //Serial.print("-");
  struct GF_Data gForceData;
  struct GF_Euler Euler;
  GF_Ret ret = GFC_GetgForceData((&gForceData), Timeout);

  if (GF_RET_OK == ret)
  {
    GF_Gesture gesture;

    switch (gForceData.type)
    {
    case GF_Data::QUATERNION:
      GFC_QuaternionToEuler(&(gForceData.value.quaternion), &Euler);
      //Serial.print(Euler.pitch);
      //Serial.print(";"); Serial.print(Euler.yaw);
      //Serial.print(";"); Serial.println(Euler.roll);
      break;

    case GF_Data::GESTURE:
      gesture = gForceData.value.gesture;
      //Serial.print("gesture: ");
      //Serial.println(gesture);

      if (gesture == GF_FIST)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_FIST_PIN, HIGH);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_SPREAD)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_SPREAD_PIN, HIGH);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_WAVEIN)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEIN_PIN, HIGH);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_WAVEOUT)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEOUT_PIN, HIGH);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_PINCH)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_PINCH_PIN, HIGH);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_SHOOT)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_SHOOT_PIN, HIGH);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_RELEASE)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_FIST_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_SPREAD_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEIN_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEOUT_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_PINCH_PIN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_SHOOT_PIN, LOW);
      }
      else if (gesture == GF_UNKNOWN)
      {
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_FIST_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_SPREAD_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEIN_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_WAVEOUT_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_PINCH_PIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(GFORCE_SHOOT_PIN, HIGH);
      }

      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
    //вывод строки со всеми элементами
   Serial.print(ret);
    Serial.print("; ");
   Serial.println(gesture);
  }
  else
  {
    //Serial.print("GFC_GetgForceData() returned: ");
    Serial.print(ret);
    Serial.print(";");
    Serial.println(0);
    
  }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
D:\reabilitation\Arduino\gForceSDKArduino-master\gForceSDKArduino-master\examples\reabil\SimpleControlByGestureC_Modded\SimpleControlByGestureC_Modded.ino:32:10: fatal error: gForceAdapterC.h.: No such file or directory
 #include <gForceAdapterC.h.>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Compilation error: gForceAdapterC.h.: No such file or directory
```

Я знаю, что эта ошибка связана с не нахождением файла, проблема в том, что у меня не библиотека, а C код, который можно и нужно сюда запихнуть, а как - не знаю :([image: C-шные файлы]